# terraform/oci - filtering a data source on defined_tags/freeform_tags does not seem to work

Tags: terraform, tags, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to filter a data source based on tags. Did anybody succeed in this ?

```
data "oci_identity_compartments" "this" {  
  compartment_id = "....."
  access_level   = "ANY"
  compartment_id_in_subtree = true

  filter {
     name   = "defined_tags:Oracle-Tags.CreatedBy"
     values = ["default/*"]    
     regex  = true
  }
}
```

Whatever I try it does not return any data (without the filter I can see all the compartments)

Comment: Documentation for oci_identity_compartments does not contain any filter block. Can you please provide a link to documentation where you found such a block?

Comment: the filter argument is indeed not listed, but it works for filtering on description, state, etc